# How to use __builtin_assume_aligned in C

Tags: c, gcc, memory-alignment, built-in

In my C code I have

```
complex float M[n][n];
complex float *delta = malloc(n * sizeof *delta);
complex float *v = malloc(n * sizeof *v);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    v[i] -= 2.*delta[j]*M[j][i];
}
```

where `i` and `n` are ints.

It was suggested I use `__builtin_assume_aligned` to make sure these are aligned in order to help auto-vectorization. However, having looked at the docs I don't understand how to do that.

How would you use it for this code?

---

The code in this question is extracted from [How to help gcc vectorize C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639654/how-to-help-gcc-vectorize-c-code) .  This is also why I want to try to align things.

Comment: I *assume* this is pseudo-ish code and that in the real code you initialize `M`, `delta` and `v` before you use them?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes absolutely. The question comes from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639654/how-to-help-gcc-vectorize-c-code .

Answer (score 8):

`__builtin_assume_aligned` is just a hint for `gcc` that the pointer is already aligned, so that it can typically vectorize the following code; it's not a directive to either `malloc` or any other memory allocation mechanism, so you might be lying to `gcc`.

To ensure that you have *actually* aligned pointers, it's your responsibility to use appropriate mechanisms. So you have to:

- either `malloc` and then roundup to the next multiple of your granularity (if not already there)
- or use [`__attribute__((aligned(N)))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) in your declarations (working for sure for heap-allocated, and possibly for stack-allocated variables)
- or use aligning memory allocation calls like [`posix_memalign`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html)

Comment: "`__builtin_assume_aligned` is just a hint." -- I think it's wrong to call it a "hint". It's a promise.

Comment: I think that “hint” as in “compilation hint” is quite common usage, but if I'm wrong your comment will help others disambiguate the meaning. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: There are compiler hints, like `__builtin_expect`. That's why it's a common usage. But that doesn't make everything a hint.