Can I specify the pointer alignment of a pointer-typed function argument in function declaration in C?
Is it possible to specify the pointer alignment of a pointer-typed function argument in function declaration in C?
For example,
void f(void *p);

How can I specify in the function signature that p's address should be a multiple of 16?
It seems __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) is a relevant one, but it specifies the alignment of &p, but not p itself.

How will this help if you can? The function is called in runtime. What will happen if the passed argument does not match this alignment? You can only check the alignment in the runtime.... And an obligatory sanity check - why do you want to do it?

OTOH, if it is not for checking but to have the compiler to assume it is aligned for optimizations and such and you are using gcc, you can use __builtin_assume_aligned as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648609/how-to-use-builtin-assume-aligned-in-c

@jylee, "p's address should be a multiple of 16?" --> this assumes that the encoding of a pointer is linear.  As far as we know pointers 0x12345555 0x12346666 are a multiple of 16 apart, even if the pointers converted to integers and then subtracted are not.

@EricPostpischil The OP is talking about passing void *, not double *.

@EugeneSh.: The principle is the same.

@EricPostpischil What principle? If the code is working with, say, some kind of communication protocol and shared memory mailbox, as apart of the protocol it might receive an address in this shared memory which is expected to contain double. The receiving side will need to either ensure this pointer is properly aligned before accessing this double or tot memcpy it or just assume it is aligned. Sure, if the code isolated and is not involving unsanitized input then these things aren't necessary,

@EugeneSh.: The principle that the caller is responsible for the function’s preconditions. If the function has a parameter that is supposed be a x-byte aligned address (which does not seem to be what OP is requesting), then the caller must pass a x-byte aligned address. It does not matter if it is an address intended to be used for a double with an eight-byte alignment requirement or an address of type void * with a 16-byte alignment requirement. The requirement for calling the function is to pass an address that meets its criteria.

As a concrete use case, I am interested in formally describing the precondition of C functions & planning to utilize C-based model checker for this (thus it is a static model checker). I am wondering whether a programmer can describe in a C function signature whether a pointer must have a specific alignment. This is analogous to the restrict quantifier of C in the sense that it is up to the caller to pass the right pointer that meets the condition.

@jylee restrict is a "promise" to the compiler, that is you can break the promise and it will break the code and the compiler won't detect it. The aforementioned __builtin is also a promise, yet it has a function-like semantics rather than type qualifier.

@EugeneSh. Unless a sanitizer for the restrict quantifier is on, which was what I had been working on for clang in the past. The __builtin is not an option since it cannot be put in the function signature. The function definition cannot have that because it is written a programming language other than C.

Clang's align_value seems to do the trick:
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#align-value

The align_value attribute can be added to the typedef of a pointer type or the declaration of a variable of pointer or reference type. It specifies that the pointer will point to, or the reference will bind to, only objects with at least the provided alignment. This alignment value must be some positive power of 2.

So this compiles:
void foo3(void * y __attribute__((align_value(32))));


So what happens when the pointer passed at run time fails to meet the compile time restriction?

It is undefined behavior: 'If the pointer value does not have the specified alignment at runtime, the behavior of the program is undefined.'

So it does nothing useful?

As I understand your question, you want to restrict a pointer argumenet to be with a specific alignment at compile time.
If this is the case - I do not think it is possible because it does not really make sense:

It is not relevant for the compiled code of f itself.

At the call site: there is no way for the compiler to ensure the alignment because it can change based on some runtime condition.
Take for example the following pseudo code:
void * get_address() {
   if (some_condition) {
       return ... // some aligned address 
   }
   else {
       return ... // some unaligned address
   } 
}

// ...

f(get_address());



If I misunderstood and you actually know that the address is aligned, then you might use compiler specific functions to notify the compiler.
For example as mentioned above in a comment, gcc has: __builtin_assume_aligned (see: How to use __builtin_assume_aligned in C).

I think in that case the semantics can be analogous to the restrict quantifier case in C, which has undefined behavior if the based-on precondition is violated.

@jylee if that's what you need the closest is __builtin_assume_aligned which is mentioned in my answer.

Can it be put at a function signatuare? This is not an answer unfortunately because the function itself is written in a language other than C and the C signature is just for foreign function interface.

I don't think this is possible, so it's the only possible answer..

The alignment required by some type is specified by the type itself and it depends on the target processor.  There's no standard way to override that, as compilers normally don't use it, but at fixing the place of variables and calculating the sizeof of that type.  Casting will not help, as normally when you cast different alignments, you only receive a warning (from GCC) if the source and destination referred types have not the same aligment.  But nothing is done at runtime, meaning that as a consequence of aligment, the pointer will not be offseted to match (which address should it be, the next or the previous address, in case of misaligment)
The programmer is responsible to do have good typing customs in the source, and if that is done, no alignment problems should arise.  Abusing void * is not a good idea, as void has an  alignment of 1 or less, just to allow any address.
